# Capture maximise/restore event in JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing

In the Java Swing tutorials, in the [How to Write an Internal Frame Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/internalframelistener.html) section it provides demo code to capture the events of closing or minimising (iconifying) a `JInternalFrame` window.

The event of maximise and restore however are not captured in the demo and there seems to be no method to capture these events in the `InternalFrameAdapter` class or an a relative field in the `InternalFrameEvent`.

How can I capture the event that the user clicked on the maximise/restore button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use [PropertyChangeListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html) and [JInternalFrame#IS_MAXIMUM_PROPERTY](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html#IS_MAXIMUM_PROPERTY):

```
//Add an internal frame listener so we can see
//what internal frame events it generates.
listenedToWindow.addInternalFrameListener(this);

listenedToWindow.addPropertyChangeListener(evt -> {
  String prop = evt.getPropertyName();
  JInternalFrame f = (JInternalFrame) evt.getSource();
  Object newValue = evt.getNewValue();
  if (JInternalFrame.IS_MAXIMUM_PROPERTY == prop) {
    String prefix;
    if (newValue == Boolean.TRUE) {
      prefix = "Internal frame maximized : ";
    } else {
      prefix = "Internal frame minimized : ";
    }
    String s = prefix + f;
    display.append(s + newline);
    display.setCaretPosition(display.getDocument().getLength());
  }
});
//...
```